# Is there a reason php's (and python's) hash function is different to my system's?

Tags: php, python, linux, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is an MD5 hash created by Python different from one created using echo and md5sum in the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693360/why-is-an-md5-hash-created-by-python-different-from-one-created-using-echo-and-m)

I just saw this, and I don't get it. Do I not know something about php's internal... something? Or are there assumptions I'm making about... something? That don't hold true?

```
$ sha512sum <(echo 'hello')
e7c22b994c59d9cf2b48e549b1e24666636045930d3da7c1acb299d1c3b7f931f94aae41edda2c2b207a36e10f8bcb8d45223e54878f5b316e7ce3b6bc019629  /proc/self/fd/11
```

and also:

```
$ echo 'hello' | sha512sum
e7c22b994c59d9cf2b48e549b1e24666636045930d3da7c1acb299d1c3b7f931f94aae41edda2c2b207a36e10f8bcb8d45223e54878f5b316e7ce3b6bc019629  -
```

but then:

```
php -a
Interactive shell
php > echo hash('sha512', 'hello');
9b71d224bd62f3785d96d46ad3ea3d73319bfbc2890caadae2dff72519673ca72323c3d99ba5c11d7c7acc6e14b8c5da0c4663475c2e5c3adef46f73bcdec043

∅ cat hashtest.php 
<?php
echo hash('sha512', 'hello');
?>
∅ php hashtest.php 
9b71d224bd62f3785d96d46ad3ea3d73319bfbc2890caadae2dff72519673ca72323c3d99ba5c11d7c7acc6e14b8c5da0c4663475c2e5c3adef46f73bcdec043
```

What's the deal? I'm on Linux x86_64, and my system text encoding is `utf-8`, and these are all ascii-range characters. I don't know what I'm overlooking.

**Interestingly**, for some value of "interesting", Python agrees with PHP:

```
>>> hashlib.sha512(b'hello').hexdigest()
'9b71d224bd62f3785d96d46ad3ea3d73319bfbc2890caadae2dff72519673ca72323c3d99ba5c11d7c7acc6e14b8c5da0c4663475c2e5c3adef46f73bcdec043'
```

Honestly, despite my humble opening, I assumed that this was some sort of massive and unknown PHP bug. But I guess not.

Comment: Indeed a duplicate, it's because of the trailing newline.

Comment: Yeah, it is. It didn't show up because when I was searching I was looking for PHP problems, and I wasn't using the other specific terminology of that post. Mine is more general: that one is a dupe of *mine*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo hash('sha512', "hello\n");
e7c22b994c59d9cf2b48e549b1e24666636045930d3da7c1acb299d1c3b7f931f94aae41edda2c2b207a36e10f8bcb8d45223e54878f5b316e7ce3b6bc019629
```

The standard `echo` command includes a trailing newline. Try `echo -n` for identical results.

Answer (score 2):

`echo` also outputs a newline after the argument. Use the `-n` option to suppress the newline:

```
$echo -n 'hello' | sha512sum
9b71d224bd62f3785d96d46ad3ea3d73319bfbc2890caadae2dff72519673ca72323c3d99ba5c11d7c7acc6e14b8c5da0c4663475c2e5c3adef46f73bcdec043  -
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is very simple. `echo` adds a newline at the end.

```
$ php -r 'echo hash(sha512, "hello\n");'
e7c22b994c59d9cf2b48e549b1e24666636045930d3da7c1acb299d1c3b7f931f94aae41edda2c2b207a36e10f8bcb8d45223e54878f5b316e7ce3b6bc019629
```

Answer (score 0):

Echo adds a newline to its argument, so you're actually hashing the string "hello\n".  When I try this string in either python or php with your sample code above, I get the e7c22... hash.  Or

```
$ echo -n 'hello' | sha512sum 
9b71d224bd62f3785d96d46ad3ea3d73319bfbc2890caadae2dff72519673ca72323c3d99ba5c11d7c7acc6e14b8c5da0c4663475c2e5c3adef46f73bcdec043  -
```