# How to get the same hash in Python3 and Mac / Linux terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, hashlib

How can I get the same sha256 hash in terminal (Mac/Linux) and Python?

Tried different versions of the examples below, and search on StackOverflow.

Terminal:

```
echo 'test text' | shasum -a 256
```

c2a4f4903509957d138e216a6d2c0d7867235c61088c02ca5cf38f2332407b00

Python3:

```
import hashlib
hashlib.sha256(str("test text").encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

'0f46738ebed370c5c52ee0ad96dec8f459fb901c2ca4e285211eddf903bf1598'

Update:
Different from [Why is an MD5 hash created by Python different from one created using echo and md5sum in the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693360/why-is-an-md5-hash-created-by-python-different-from-one-created-using-echo-and-m) because in Python3 you need to explicitly encode, and I need the solution in Python, not just in terminal. The "duplicate" will not work on files:

example.txt content:

```
test text
```

Terminal:

```
shasum -a 256 example.txt
```

c2a4f4903509957d138e216a6d2c0d7867235c61088c02ca5cf38f2332407b00

Comment: I thought it might works with `b'test test'` instead of encoding it as utf-8, but it doesn't seem to...

Comment: Question (that was deleted) asking for possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693360/why-is-an-md5-hash-created-by-python-different-from-one-created-using-echo-and-m It is the same root cause, but different commands on the terminal and in Python. The old answer is Python2, in Python3 you need to explicit encode with str("test text").encode('utf-8'). So I will almost say no.

Comment: You don't need the `str` constructor call, so better leave that out. Also here the OP is `shasum`, so there is a slight benefit in googleability for keeping this (but closed as dup)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `echo` built-in will add a trailing newline yielding a different string, and thus a different hash. Do it like so

```
echo -n 'test text' | shasum -a 256
```

If you indeed intended to also hash the newline (I advice against this as it violates [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)), it needs to be fixed up in python like so

```
hashlib.sha256("{}\n".format("test text").encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```